# MySQL - find orphan rows

Tags: mysql

I have two MySQL tables (testa, resa) like the small sample shown below:

```
       CREATE TABLE RESA (
       `tdate` date,
       `reg` varchar(4), 
       `num` int(2), 
       `P1`  int(2), 
       `P2`  int(2),    
       `P3`  int(2), 
       `P4`  int(2)   
       ); 

       CREATE TABLE TESTA (
       `tdate` date,
       `reg` varchar(4), 
       `numa` int(2), 
       `numb` int(2),
       `name` varchar(10),
       `reso` varchar(2)
       );

       INSERT INTO RESA VALUES 
       ("2015-12-06", 'NERA', 2, 1,2,3,4),
       ("2015-12-06", 'WAS', 5, 5,6,7,9),
       ("2015-12-08", 'NERA', 1, 3,5,6,8);

      INSERT INTO TESTA VALUES 
      ("2015-12-06", 'NERA', 2,1, 'Qalyub',""),
      ("2015-12-06", 'NERA', 2,2, 'Kunjin',""),
      ("2015-12-06", 'NERA', 2,3, 'Carrizal',""),
      ("2015-12-07", 'NERA', 2,4, 'Amur',""),
      ("2015-12-06", 'NERA', 2,6, 'Heni',""),
      ("2015-12-06", 'NERA', 2,7, 'El Moro',""),
      ("2015-12-07", 'NERA', 2,10, 'Fifth-C',""),
      ("2015-12-06", 'WAS', 5,2, 'Bora',""),
      ("2015-12-06", 'WAS', 5,3, 'Imjin',""),
      ("2015-12-06", 'WAS', 5,5, 'RR',""),
      ("2015-12-07", 'WAS', 5,6, 'Qalyub',""),
      ("2015-12-06", 'WAS', 5,7, 'RR',""),
      ("2015-12-07", 'WAS', 5,9, 'Qalyub',""),
      ("2015-12-07", 'NERA', 1,2, 'Kunjin',""),
      ("2015-12-07", 'NERA', 1,3, 'Carrizal',""),
      ("2015-12-07", 'NERA', 1,5, 'Amur',""),
      ("2015-12-07", 'NERA', 1,6, 'Bora',""),
      ("2015-12-07", 'NERA', 1,7, 'Imjin',""),
      ("2015-12-07", 'NERA', 1,8, 'Magboy',"") ;
```

Actual tables have thousands of rows, and other columns.

For each RESA row there is a variable number of associated TESTA rows where the first 3 fields of each table (date,reg,num/date,reg,numa) establish the relationship .  Rows are distinct in both tables, ie no duplicates.

There is at least 2 test (TESTA) rows for every experiment results (RESA) row.

When the first 3 fields of each table match there will be a match for RESA.p1 and TESTA.numb in just one of the TESTA rows, so the following will return all the related rows from both tables which will be used to apply updates to other cols in TESTA:

```
SELECT * FROM TESTA as T
  NATURAL JOIN RESA AS R
  WHERE T.numb = R.p1;
```

As such the count of TESTA rows to be updated should match the count of rows in table RESA, ie the below counts will be the same:

```
mysql>SELECT count(*) FROM TESTA as T
           NATURAL JOIN RESA AS R
           WHERE T.numb = R.p1;



mysql>SELECT COUNT(*) FROM RESA;
```

In the sample data they are not the same and this is the problem I'm trying to identify.  In the small sample the culprit is easy to find: RESA.tdate in the last row: ("2015-12-08", 'NERA', 1, 3,5,6,8); is incorrect and should be "2015-12-07" matching the related data in TESTA.

My question is how can I identify the orphans in RESA with a much larger database, ie those rows that do not have related data in TESTA?

The inverse of the above:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM TESTA as T
           NATURAL JOIN RESA AS R
           WHERE T.numb != R.p1;
```

does not work as there is no NATURAL JOIN of the related fields as RESA has a unique (ie does not exist in TESTA and is incorrect) tdate value.

My actual database has thousands of rows and there are 2 discrepancies, is there a script I can use to identify them?

Comment: Take a look at this blog post of mine, which has several options for finding orphaned rows: http://mechanics.flite.com/blog/2016/02/05/finding-and-deleting-orphaned-rows-in-mysql/

Comment: Thanks Ike, on the money here.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

So something like a `LEFT JOIN`?

```
SELECT t.* FROM RESA t
LEFT OUTER JOIN TESTA s
 ON(t.tdate = s.tdate AND t.reg = s.reg and t.num = s.numa)
WHERE s.tdate is null
```

Or with `NOT EXISTS()` :

```
SELECT t.* FROM RESA t
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM TESTA s
                 WHERE t.tdate = s.tdate
                   AND t.reg = s.reg 
                   AND t.num = s.numa)
```

Comment: Thanks for that quick response, both solutions work famously.

Comment: I know this was back in 2016, but I just found your solutions, and they are simple yet absolutely perfect!  Thank you!